# Posterous instructions for adding Google Analytics do not cover the code snippet to be pasted in the <head>

Tags: google-analytics

The Posterous instructions for [adding Google Analytics](http://help.posterous.com/how-to-add-google-analytics-to-your-site#google_analytics) ends with pasting the Google Analytics Domain ID into the settings page.

However, the instructions given by Google tell me to paste some JavaScript code into the `<head>`.

How do I get around with this?

1. Do I **need** to paste the JavaScript code?
2. If I do **need** to paste the JavaScript code, can I just paste it into the custom HTML/CSS style specification of my Posterous Space?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the code snippet - Posterous is apparently embedding the snippet *for* you, so all you need to do is [find your account number](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?answer=81977) and enter it.